# "undefined" Error with onchange Event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it so when I press a button, it will print a different number depending on which button I press. **I want the buttons to look the same**. This is what I have:

```
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center onchange="myFunction">

    <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1">
    <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

    <div class="check"></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3">
    <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2">
    <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

    <div class="check"><div class="inside"></div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<p id="paragraph" align="center">0</p>

<script>

function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("radiobuttons").value;
    document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = x;
}

</script>
```

Although, when I press a button, it says undefined. What does this mean, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`change` event is not invoked for a `div` element. You will have to attach it to the radio buttons explicitly for them to be invoked.

Also it is a good idea to avoid inline event handlers and attach the handlers in JS to avoid dirtying the `HTML`

**HTML**

```
<div id="radiobuttons" class="container" name="buttons" align=center>

  <h2>I Want my Building to be Made of:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="brick-option" name="material" value="1">
      <label for="brick-option">Bricks</label>

      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="wood-option" name="material" value="3">
      <label for="wood-option">Wood</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="stone-option" name="material" value="2">
      <label for="stone-option">Stone</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<p id="paragraph" align="center">0</p>
```

**JS**

```
var radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');

for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
  radioButtons[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = this.value;
    }
  });
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/attfm15z/)**

Comment: Can you make it so it outputs a variable instead of printing it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @NathanChan You cannot return a value from the invocation of the handler. The best think you can do is, have a global variable and set the value of the variable.

Comment: I meant can you make it change a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a property of `value` on `radiobuttons` which is a `<div>` that has no such value, this is why you're getting 'undefined'.

You'll want to modify your code so that `myFunction` is assigned to the inline event handler `onClick` of each *radio button* input instead.